# Find the longest word in the dictionary such that it can be built from successively adding a single character to a previous word

Tags: string, dictionary

I found following question and decider to share one of the possible solutions.

Question:

**Suppose you are given a dictionary of words based on an alphabet with a fixed number of characters. Please write a method / function which will find the longest word in the dictionary such that it can be built from successively adding a single character to an existing word in the dictionary (in any location).**

For instance, “a” -> “at” -> “cat” -> “chat” -> “chart”.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Successive adding of char to get the longest word in the dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534087/successive-adding-of-char-to-get-the-longest-word-in-the-dictionary)

Comment: Yes, I took the idea for the solution from that post (unfortunately it is closed so I created new one).  It has two solutions, one is brute force that generates all possible words starting with a single character. Second one goes from the biggest word down by deleting characters. This solution does some pre-computation and generates answer for each character and needs sorted dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I took the idea to solve the problem from this post: [Successive adding of char to get the longest word in the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534087/successive-adding-of-char-to-get-the-longest-word-in-the-dictionary)

Basically, it iterates over each word in a dictionary and generates path by removing characters from the string recursively until new word is not in a dictionary or size 1. If last word is a target character, I found possible maximum path. Assuming dictionary is given as a hash-map, the runtime is O(n*k^2) where n is the number of words in a dictionary and k is the length of the biggest string (worst case). I believe it can be optimized by pruning some words, for ex. words that do not contain target character.

It returns set of strings (to simplify coding). For ex. if target character is 'a', this function returns: 
[tamped, stamped, ta, a, tape, tap, taped, stampedes, stampede]

I would appreciate any thoughts on this solution.

```
    public static Set<String> findLongestPath(char targetChar, 
Set<String> dictionary) {

        Set<String> maxPath = new HashSet<String>();

        for (String word: dictionary) {
            Set<String> currentPath = findPath(word, dictionary, targetChar);
            if (maxPath.size() < currentPath.size()) {
                maxPath = currentPath;
            }
        }
        return maxPath;
    }

    public static Set<String> findPath(String word, Set<String> dictionary, char targetChar) {
        String targetCharStr = "" + targetChar;
        Set<String> path = new HashSet<String>();

        if (word.length() == 1) {
            path.add(word);
        } else if (dictionary.contains(word)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                //remove one character from a word and try to find path for it
                String subWord = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
                Set<String> deepPath = findPath(subWord, dictionary, targetChar);
                //stop if path contains word with a single character wich is a target character
                if (deepPath.contains(targetCharStr)) {
                    path.add(word);
                    path.addAll(deepPath);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

```
And here is small driver:
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        char targetChar = 'a';
        Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader dictionaryFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/usr/share/dict/words"));
        String line;
        while ((line = dictionaryFile.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("'")) { continue; }
            dictionary.add(line.toLowerCase().trim());
        }
        dictionaryFile.close();

        System.out.println(findLongestPath(targetChar, dictionary));    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a great example of Dynamic programming. I would look into the dynammic programming section of this book http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/all.pdf . He starts with very simple examples and builds to complex ones in a way that makes a lot of sense.

The challenge with DP is to build solutions that operate in polynomial time. Most DP solutions are O(n^2), which is still better than exponential (such as trying every combination in the dictionary). The solution will involve using arrays to build up information that will continue to build on itself and lead to something with an answer